# Using `SafeHandle` for a C API, that includes reference counting

Tags: c#, unmanagedresources, safehandle

I am working on Python interop. Internally, Python keeps reference counters for all objects via `Py_IncRef` and `Py_DecRef`. I want to ensure proper finalization of pointers to Python objects, so I am trying to create a class `PyHandle` derived from `SafeHandle`, that would call `Py_DecRef` on `ReleaseHandle`.

Problem is: unlike, for example, Windows API, Python does not increment refcount before returning a pointer to an object. So when interop creates an instance of `PyHandle`, I want it to call `Py_IncRef` on the pointer. However, I do not see a method I could override for that to happen. `SafeHandle` constructor takes invalid handle value, and there is no `AcquireHandle` to override. CoreCLR code also has non-overridable `SetHandle` method (see [SafeHandle.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/bd8e35e41e6a6e626c4fc623845ec40b7704d109/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/InteropServices/SafeHandle.cs)).

What can I do to make the call to `Py_IncRef` when `PyHandle` is constructed by interop?

Is `SafeHandle` the right tool for the task?

Answer (score 0):

`SafeHandle` has no public method to pass a handle to it. So feel free to call `Py_IncRef` *before* you pass the handle to the protected base methods.

However, `SafeHandle` might be somewhat overkill for your purpose as it maintains its own reference counter which is not really required for a handle that maintains it's own reference count.

Comment: AFAIR, I am not supposed to explicitly pass `IntPtr` to `SafeHandle`. Instead, interop code should do it automatically (???). E.g. when I define `extern PyHandle PyFunc(...);` internal CLR interop code creates `PyHandle` instance, and sets its raw pointer.